# Automatic code-trolling disclaimer

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, code-trolling

One of the rules for posting a [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) question is to clearly state that the question is a code-trolling question. Therefore most questions include the below disclaimer recommended by the tag's wiki

> <sup>Note: This is a [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) question. Please do not take the question and/or answers seriously. More information [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tags/code-trolling/info).</sup>

No one would bother writing their own disclaimer anyway, so why just don't automatically add the above disclaimer to questions tagged [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling)?

- Prevents disclaimer-less code-trolling questions
- Saves time

There are few pros, but what are the cons?

Comment: Leaving side my dislike for subjective contests, I would say that if a category of challenges needs a disclaimer, we should be asking ourselves if it is appropriate for the site *at all*.

Comment: What you are requesting is easy enough by simple editing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why have the Stack Exchange devs program *an entirely new feature* just for a *single tag*, especially when most of us regulars don't even like the tag at all?

You know, if the questions need to each individually have their own "disclaimer," maybe they shouldn't even exist. The first one was great, but the now steady stream of low quality code trolling questions is... disheartening, to say the least.

Anyway, it's not that hard to copy and paste a little block of Markdown, if you really want to.

Comment: For answers, there is already something like that, but not for questions.

Comment: @JohannesKuhn, pardon my ignorance. What are you referring to?

Comment: Something like that: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210389/open-source-advertising-sidebar-1h-2014

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue is that questions are written- and askers are thinking- in the wrong way when it comes to [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) problems.

Instead of "how do i x?  - insert disclaimer", how about something like "Write a piece of code that appears to do *x*, but actually *y* instead"?  This both makes it clear what the goal of the question is, and reinforces the fact that answers like `print 'x'` aren't acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking of "outside" users. I would be in favour of the idea of both question **and answers** being auto-framed or headered/footered with some sort of disclaimer.

Answers to [code-trolling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-trolling) questions are, by definition, "useless and frustrating" so if SEO takes brings an outside user to a page here with this sort of content, I think a bold/newbie disclaimer prevents innocent victims from taking things seriously and adding their own frustrated noise in comments.

Unless the goal is *true* trolling.  If so, carry on. :)

Comment: If you're gonna troll, troll hard.  I guess that's a philosophy I already live by, so +1.

Comment: Ha! It's not mine, but it's a reasonable position!